# How to run integration tests in standalone Wildfly 9.0.2 FInal?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb, integration-testing

I am trying to build a REST application using JavaEE and need to write integration test for update method.

My application looks like this:

Item entity

```
@Entity
public class Item {...}
```

A corresponding Controller that handles all REST requests

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/item")
public class ItemController {

    @GET
    public Response getItems(){
        return Response.ok(ItemService.getItems()).build();
    }

}
```

And the Item Service, that is injected into Controller

```
@Stateless
public class ItemService {

    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return em.createNativeQuery <...>  //find items
    }

    public void updateItemById(Item item) {
        ... 
        em.merge(item)
        ...
    }

}
```

I am struggling to understand how to run an integration test without using any testing framework, such as Arquillian.

Application is deployed in Wildfly 9.0.2 Final as war. I suspect that I probably should write a profile that would run integration test similar to this:
https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/articles-test-it

But after trying to run integration-test for hours I feel like giving up. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

EDIT: After struggling for a while, I decided to use Arquillian for this task. Now I only need to test whether or not Optimistic Locking is working on my program (which it does, but the task was to write a test for it).

Comment: Having more than one class to be tested I would not call integrationtest. Perhaps you have a look at ioc-unit, a simple example for JPA is: https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/tree/master/examples2/ex1-1entity another example using resteasy is: https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/ioc-unit-resteasy/src/test/java/com/oneandone/iocunit/resteasytester/TheTest.java

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence: "Having more than one class to be tested I would not call integration test?" Because I thought integration tests are simply the ones that actually use several real classes without mocking, that is why I called these tests integration tests.
 
Thanks for examples. Although we finally decided to use Arquillian, which was not that hard to set up.

Comment: Arquillian,is very good, especially if you want to have exactly the destination environment. My problems with arquillian are the integration in an IDE, because the development of the testcode lasts at least as long as the development of the working code. Often the duration of the arquillian startup for a single test is difficult to bare during development.

Comment: In my opinion ... an integration test actually uses several real deployables. Otherwise I would not talk about integration. To just test a single class in a well structured application is seldomly reasonable. I think it is even dangerous. I often saw logic which was to be tested to rewritten in the testing class. Unit tests of single classes also often lead to practically not refactorable code because mocks often heavily depend on internas of the classes they mock.

Comment: Okay... But then in my case, when I test a real service (or resource) that has a connection to a database to check whether or not a method throws OptimisticLockException -  can I safely call it an integration test or not? (Another question if this test is even a reasonable one...)

Comment: In my opinion, that is a simple unit test and simple to achieve. Mocking a database using mockito by intercepting JPA in my opinion is one of the biggest sins when creating UnitTests. No Test of statements, fixed on the structure of the entitys mostly fixed sequence of calls necessary. That kills all possibilities to safely refactor the code in an invariant way.

Comment: Oh I do not mock JPA - using arquillian I deploy normal application, but only a part of it and then use my default persistenceUnit to connect to a real database. I guess you are saying it is pointless to write this test in general?

Comment: No, actually I proposed something similar by defining @SutClasses. It just depends on how big the part of the application is you want to test. As I wrote earlier Arquillian is quite capable in supporting you there, I would not call such a test integration test. I searched for a possibility to integrate the Unit-Test-Framework better in my IDE, support JUnit5, more control in asynchronous and timers, avoid indeterministic tests,... And developed that using ioc-unit...

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will have a more thorough look at your ioc-unit in the meantime.